# Problem attaching files to nodes with Services

Tags: 7, services

I'm trying to attach files (images) to nodes via Services 3 from an external app using JavaScript.

From what I understand (and doing) is:

1) Create a node posting JSON to my endpoint domain.com/api/node.json

```
{
  "type":"foo",
  "title":"Hello World",
  "language":"und",
  "body":{"und":{"0":{"value":"Body Text"}}},
}
```

2) Create file posting JSON to my endpoint domain.com/api/file.json

```
{
  "filename":"image.jpg",
  "target_uri":"public://image.jpg",
  "filemime":"image/jpeg",
  "file":"myBase64String"
}
```

No problem at all at this point.

Then when trying to attach the files created to the node, is where I have trouble, not http errors, simply nothing happens.

First I have tried posting JSON to my endpoint domain.com/api/node/*nid/attach_file after successfully creating a new file, and getting back the fid

```
{
  "field_name":"foo",
  "filename":"image.jpg",
  "fid":"*fid"
}
```

Returning Status 200 OK empty text, but when viewing the node remains the same without the file attached.

I have also tried to create the files first and then when posting for node creation adding the fid, the node is created but no file attached.

```
{
  "type":"foo",
  "title":"Hello World",
  "language":"und",
  "body":{"und":{"0":{"value":"Body Text"}}},
  "field_foo":{"und":{"0":{"fid":"*fid"}}}
}
```

My field is a field type Image, widget Image. I have also tried in another field type file, with same results.

If someone can give me a heads up, what am I doing wrong or what is missing. I can't find any explanatory documentation on line.

Thank you.

Comment: Try removing the `und` language code from `field_foo`, and/or change `field_foo` to: `field_foo: { und: [ { fid: 123 } ]}`

Comment: I have explained the method I used to attach a file to a node in here (hope it help) http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/156015/services-3-updating-a-custom-field-in-a-user-account

Answer (score 0):

try adding more data to the attached file (it might be that fid and filename is not enough I can't find the example I used a long time ago, which had a similar problem):

- alt (might be required in general or only if marked as required in bundle)
- title (might be required in general or only if marked as required in bundle)
- uid
- filemime
- uri
- status = 1
- display = 1

Some references I could find quickly:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129559/attaching-image-files-to-nodes-programmatically-in-drupal-7
- this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19930610/1158887
- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/120078/is-it-safe-to-reuse-the-fid-file-id

Comment: Thank you Andre-B. I have figured out that it actually works, the problem was (is) that the file field was set to accept up to 4 files, if I set it to accept only one file it does work. Any clue on how can I attach multiple files within the same file field?

Comment: "field_foo":{"und":{"0":{"fid":"*fid"}}} did you try to use a real array here? "field_foo":{"und":{[{"fid":"*fid"}, {"fid":"*fid"}]}}? maybe search for multivalue fields and services

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is related to the issue I raised on the Services module issue queue [File is created but can't view it in the browser](https://www.drupal.org/node/2793403).

I tried a few times to save a file by attaching the base64 encoded data, returned by Javascript whenever I load a file from my application.

I could only make it work by removing the base64 identifier at the beginning of the string which seems too much of a hack... So I modified Services' file resource, using *file_get_contents()* in order to retrieve the image content.

You can find a patch on the issue page. Word of caution, although , I simply replace a function, this patch hasn't yet been tested!